# Python precise stopwatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, stopwatch

I am trying to add a stopwatch to my Python code but I'm struggling to get something even remotely accurate. I need time displayed as such :
minutes : seconds : milliseconds

00:00:000

Yes... Three digits for the milliseconds is what I'm aiming for.

The method using (elapsedTime - startTime) does not fit my needs since I want a timer/clock to be displayed on-screen.

The method I am currently using is a function looping at high speed but can't have those three digits for the milliseconds.

Here is the code I'm using :

```py
from tkinter import *

ms=0; sc=0; mn=0; stp=0
playertime = 0

def resetchrono(): 
    global ms,sc,mn,stp
    ms=0
    sc=0
    mn=0
    stp=0

def startchrono():
    global sc,mn,ms
    ms=ms+1
    if(ms==10):
        sc=sc+1
        ms=0
    if(sc==60):
        mn=mn+1
        sc=0
    if(stp==0):
        display_time ['text'] = '%i:%i.%i'%(mn,sc,ms)
        display_time.after(100,startchrono)

def stopchrono():
    global stp
    playertime = str('%i:%i.%i'%(mn,sc,ms))
    stp=1

root = Tk()

buttonstart = Button(root, text="Start", command=lambda:[resetchrono(), startchrono()]).pack()
buttonstop = Button(root, text="Sop", command=stopchrono).pack()
display_time = Label(root, justify="center", font="ariel 50", background="black", foreground="red", width=5)
display_time.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Does anyone have a better way to do that ?
This code seems to work quite Ok but there is some "latency" in its execution and I'd like to hear your take on this.

Comment: Your code is not working, please provide a reproducible example. And have you tried taking a look at the `time` module ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

Comment: I updated the code.

Yes, I did check the time module but could'nt find anything useful for me. I can use it to set a "start" time, define an "end" time and then do simple math to get the exact amount of time elapsed between these two.

However, it does not provide a dynamic time display like in my example above. And this is what I need.